# Difficulty in Making HTTP Login Request with Requests Library(Python)

Tags: python, http

This is my first time posting on stack so I'll do my best to get right to the point regarding my issue. I've just begun delving into the formulation of HTTP requests for web scraping purposes and I decided to choose one site to practice logging in using the requests library in python. I already took the liberty of extracting the csrfKey from the html on the first get but after the post, I still end up on the login page with the fields filled out but I do not successfully log in. Any help would be much appreciated as I'm completely stumped on what I should try next. Thank you all!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent':'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
    'auth':'username',
    'password':'pass',
    'login_standard_submitted:':'1',
    'remember_me':'0',
    'remember_me_checkbox':'1',
    'signin_anonymous':'0'
}


s = requests.Session()

r = s.get("http://www.gaming-asylum.com/forums/index.php?/",headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
payload['csrfKey'] = str(soup.find('input',{'name':'csrfKey'}).get('value'))


headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
headers['Referer'] = 'http://www.gaming-asylum.com/forums/?_fromLogout=1&_fromLogin=1'
headers['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests']='1'
headers['Origin']='http://www.gaming-asylum.com'

r= s.post("http://www.gaming-asylum.com/forums/index.php?/login/",headers=headers,data=payload)
```

Comment: Use fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to watch the request made by your web browser and the request made by your script. Keep adjusting your script until your request is indistinguishable from the browser's request. Rinse, lather, repeat until you have what you want.

Comment: I do have fiddler on my home computer but what would that be providing me that analyzing the network tab in Chrome would not? Also, when you say keep watching the request made by my script what exactly do you mean? Isnt the request going to post exactly as its outlined in the script?

Comment: Chrome won't watch the request made *by your script*. You need to make sure that your request is *actually* identical, not just identical in theory.

Comment: Will fiddler watch a request made by my script by default or do I need to point it elsewhere? In addition, When you look a request through your browser, how should be determining whether a request header needs to be added to the scripts request? There are a bunch of headers I dont add in the script but that can be seen in the browser's network tab like "Encoding-type" etc